# How to get detailed information of users authenticated with Waffle?

Tags: spring, spring-security, waffle

I am using Spring Security combined with Waffle to authenticate the users of my webapp. I configured Spring Security with the following configuration:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider;
import waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider;
import waffle.servlet.spi.SecurityFilterProvider;
import waffle.servlet.spi.SecurityFilterProviderCollection;
import waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilter;
import waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint;
import waffle.windows.auth.impl.WindowsAuthProviderImpl;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint entryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private NegotiateSecurityFilter filter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);
        http.addFilterBefore(filter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public WindowsAuthProviderImpl windowsAuthProviderImpl() {
        return new WindowsAuthProviderImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider negotiateSecurityFilterProvider(final WindowsAuthProviderImpl authProvider) {
        return new NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public BasicSecurityFilterProvider basicSecurityFilterProvider(final WindowsAuthProviderImpl authProvider) {
        return new BasicSecurityFilterProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterProviderCollection securityFilterProviderCollection(
            final NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider negotiateSecurityFilterProvider,
            final BasicSecurityFilterProvider basicSecurityFilterProvider) {
        return new SecurityFilterProviderCollection(new SecurityFilterProvider[] { negotiateSecurityFilterProvider,
                basicSecurityFilterProvider });
    }

    @Bean
    public NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint(
            final SecurityFilterProviderCollection securityFilterProviderCollection) {
        final NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint entryPoint = new NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint();

        entryPoint.setProvider(securityFilterProviderCollection);

        return entryPoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public NegotiateSecurityFilter negotiateSecurityFilter(
            final SecurityFilterProviderCollection securityFilterProviderCollection) {
        final NegotiateSecurityFilter filter = new NegotiateSecurityFilter();

        filter.setProvider(securityFilterProviderCollection);

        return filter;
    }

}
```

The authentication process is working as expected, but I can only read the name of the currently logged in user in a controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public @ResponseBody String index(final Principal user) {
    return String.format("Welcome to the home page, %s!", user.getName());
}
```

For the authorization I would like to assign roles to the users that I define in a database and additional information (like email-adresses, phone number, etc.) are stored in Active Directory. How can these information automatically be merged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created another filter that is fired after the Waffle filter ran. It checks if Waffle authenticated a user. If so, I create my own `Authentication` object with the information from the Waffle object.

**Update**

In the meantime I went back to form based login. But I think I did it like this:

A custom `UserDetails` class:

```
@Data
public class User implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -302856598965676658L;

    private String username;

    private Set<Role> authorities;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

A custom `GrantedAuthority` class:

```
@Data
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7912276892872811638L;

    private String authority;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }

}
```

The custom authentication class:

```
public class CustomAuthentication implements Authentication {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1723253799961522167L;

    private User user;

    public CustomAuthentication(final User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return user.getAuthorities();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDetails() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return user != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    }

}
```

The custom filter:

```
@Component
public class CustomFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        final SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        final Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();

        if (authentication != null) {
            final String username = authentication.getName();
            final User user = userService.getUserByUsername(username);
            final CustomAuthentication customAuthentication = new CustomAuthentication(user);

            securityContext.setAuthentication(customAuthentication);
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

The registration of the filters:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private NegotiateSecurityFilter waffleFilter;

    @Autowired
    private CustomFilter customFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(waffleFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterAfter(customFilter, NegotiateSecurityFilter.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: @dataCore I updated my answer. Please note that I did not test the code.

Comment: @SteffenKreutz - Thank you for the answer. Can you please help me with one more challenge? I want to authenticate and authorize (check in the DB) some end-points but only authenticate the others. Is there a way?

Comment: @JHS Please ask a new question for this topic.